# Fetch value of Datatables column having property "bVisible: false"

Tags: jquery, datatables

In my Datatables, I have used `bVisible : false` property to hide column. But I want to get data from all columns whether it is hidden or not on click event in jQuery. How can I get all hidden column data?

This is the way I have hidden 5th column:

```js
$('#abc').dataTable( {
    "bDestroy": true,
    "aaSorting" :[],
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aoColumns": [ null,null,{ "sType": "numeric-comma" },null,{"bVisible": false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null ] 
});
```

I am getting value of that column using this code:

```js
$(this).closest('tr').find("#xyz").text();
```

Here `xyz` is required column td id.

Comment: Define "get data from all columns". Get how? You mean you can search them all?

Comment: I want to fetch data from all columns and want to display in popup modal on click event.I have tried but not getting hidden column data.

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried to the question?

Comment: This is the way I have hidden 5th column :$('#abc').dataTable( {
        "bDestroy": true,
        "aaSorting" :[],
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aoColumns": [
        null,null,{ "sType": "numeric-comma" },null,{"bVisible": false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null
       ]
      });   Now I am getting value of that column using this code : $(this).closest('tr').find("#xyz").text();   here xyz is required column td id.

Comment: it is like <td id="xyz">. This column is hidden and I am trying to get that column value.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. Since they are not in the HTML at all, you can not simply get them via the ID. You can use `$("#tableName").DataTable().data()` to get all the data (including the hidden fields), but the ID is lost.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the version of Datatables you're using...

< 1.9 (ish)

```
var table = $('#abc').dataTable(dtoptions);

$('#abc').on('click', '.someclicktarget', function(ev) {
  //need the ELEMENT, the the jquery object
  var row = $(this).closest('tr').get(0);

  var data = table.fnGetData(row);

  doSomethingWith(data[indexOfHiddenColumn]);
});
```

> 1.9.4 (ish)

```
var table = $('#abc').DataTable(dtoptions);

table.on('click', '.someclicktarget', function(ev) {
  //>=1.10 can operate on either jquery objects OR plain elements
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');

  var data = table.row(row).data();

  doSomethingWith(data[indexOfHiddenColumn]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here indexOfHiddenColumn means at which position column is added to table. I mean 0,1,2 etc.  If this is true then is there any other options without giving index of column hard coded.because index will be changed if I add any new column in table.

Comment: Yeah, your page logic will need to deal with that complexity if necessary. This is just meant to be a simple example to demonstrate how the DataTables API works. Integrating it with your application is beyond the scope of answers on Stack Overflow.