# jQuery DataTables get hidden column data in

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
$("#TransactionTable").DataTable({
                    ajax: {
                        url: '/Transaction/SearchMockup',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            cardEndingWith: $("#ccn").val(),
                            status: $("#status").val(),
                            supplier: $("#supplier").val(),
                            fromDate: $("#fromDate").val(),
                            toDate: $("#toDate").val()
                        }
                    },
                    columns: [
                    {
                    { data: 'Status' },
                    { data: 'TransactionId' },
                    { data: 'CreditCardNumber' },
                    { data: 'Supplier' },
                    { data: 'CreatedAt' },
                    { data: 'Amount' },
                    { data: 'Guid' }
                    ],
                    columnDefs: [
                    {
                        "targets": [6],
                        "visible": false,
                        "className": "guid"
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [1],
                        "className": "transactionIdColumn",
                    }
                    ]
                });
```

Have that table definition, want on click at "TransactionId" column, to get the value/data of the hidden "Guid" column. My guid column have class name called "transactionIdColumn" as you can see. Need help with the jQuery Code.

Try to do something like this:

```
$("#TransactionTable .transactionIdColumn").on('click', function (elm) {
                var guidNumber = $(elm).closest("tr").find(".transactionIdColumn").html();
                alert(guidNumber);
            });
```

[image]

Comment: As written, `var guidNumber = $(elm).closest("tr").find(".transactionIdColumn").html();` looks to be equivalent to `var guidNumber = $(this).html();`. Changing that `.find()` selector should give you a fighting chance.

Comment: Use the datatable api to access the data ... see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36695886/1175966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
{ "data"  : "TransactionId",
  "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
              var guid = full['guid'];
              return '<a href="#" class="trans_id" data-guid="'+guid+'"> '+data+' </a>';
            }
},
```

Here is the link to the [datatables.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

```
 $("#TransactionTable .trans_id").on('click', function (elm) {
     var guidNumber = $(this).data('guid');
     alert(guidNumber);
 });
```